# Sharing class in angular module

Tags: angular, module

I would like to have in shared module class that I can import in other modules. Something like this:

```
import { SomeClass } from '/path/to/shared/module'
```

I want to avoid directly importing class like

```
import { SomeClass } from '/path/to/class'
```

Basically I want something like importing from packages in Java or from namespace in c#. I can find *only* using components, services or directives, from shared modules but no classes. I know I can use barrel files but this seems like better solution for my needs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a shared module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47398896/how-to-create-a-shared-module)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use path aliases**

folder structure:

```
src
└── shared
    ├── module1
    │   ├── index.ts
    │   └── module1.module.ts
    └── module2
        ├── index.ts
        └── module2.module.ts
```

src/shared/module1/index.ts

```
export * from './module1.module.ts'
```

src/shared/module2/index.ts

```
export * from './module2.module.ts'
```

add alias in tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "paths": {
      "@shared/*": ["src/app/shared/*"],
    }
  }
}
```

and that's how you use it:

```
import { Module1 } from '@shared/module1';
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the same pattern as doing it with a component, service, directive, etc...

Figure out a good home for any shared classes throughout your application.

Your shared class:

```
export class SomeClass {
    ...
}
```

Any place you want to use your share class:

```
import { SomeClass } './path/to/shared/class';
```

Take a look at some of the examples on MDN:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/import

However, if you're trying to make this super "angularized", you may want to look at using a [library](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries)